# How to perform Web3 & MetaMask user sign in

Tags: web3js, metamask

I'm new to blockchain development and would like to build an app with node.js, express.js, next.js, web3, meta mask for user sign in. Are there any good docs that would help me out thank you.

Comment: What are you using at the front-end, react? Popular options would be web3-react or WalletConnect

Comment: I'm using Next.js

Comment: Sorry, was mistaken it with nestjs. I think nextjs is based on React, right. So mentioned tools should work.

Comment: @wslyvh Have you had any experience with web-3 react? I'm going to start with that first.

Comment: I do. Using it with hooks. Their documentation is quite good: https://github.com/NoahZinsmeister/web3-react/tree/v6/docs 
if you're looking for an example check out https://github.com/wslyvh/contraktor/ mainly on index and components/accountcontrol 

Hope that helps!